# swift 3 filter array of dictionaries by string value of key in dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, filter

I have a class such as this

```
class FoundItem : NSObject {

var id : String!
var itemName : String!
var itemId : Int!
var foundBy : String!
var timeFound : String!

init(id: String,
    itemName: String,
    itemId: Int,
    foundBy: String,
    timeFound: String)

{
    self.id = id
    self.itemName = itemName
    self.itemId = itemId
    self.foundBy = foundBy
    self.timeFound = timeFound

}
```

and I reference it on my

```
class MapViewVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

var found = [FoundItem]()

var filterItemName : String()

}
```

My `FoundItem` are generated by into an array of dictionaries from my class of `FoundItem` from a firebase query. I then get a string of that `itemName` that is generated from an another view controller that is a collection view on the `didSelection` function. I want to take that string and then filter or search the arrays with the string `itemName` that is equal from the `itemName` string from my previous `viewController`. Then removed the array of dictionaries that are not equal to the `itemName`. Not just the objects, but the entire array that contains non-equal key, value pair. I have looked for days, and I am stuck on filtering an array of dictionaries created from a class. I have looked and tried NSPredicates, for-in loops, but all that ends up happening is creating a new array or bool that finds my values or keys are equal. Here is the current function I have written.

```
func filterArrayBySearch() {

    if self.filterItemName != nil {

        dump(found)

        let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemName like %@", "\(filterItemName)")
        let nameFilter = found.filter { namePredicate.evaluate(with: $0) }

        var crossRefNames = [String: [FoundItem]]()
        for nameItemArr in found {
            let listName = nameItem.itemName
            let key = listName

            if crossRefNames.index(forKey: key!) != nil {

                crossRefNames[key!]?.append(nameItemArr)

                if !("\(key)" == "\(filterItemName!)") {

                    print("------------- Success have found [[[[[[    \(key!)    ]]]]]] and \(filterItemName!) to be equal!!")

                     // crossRefNames[key!]?.append(nameItemArr)

                } else {

                    print("!! Could not find if \(key!) and \(filterItemName!) are equal !!")
                }


            } else {

                crossRefNames[key!] = [nameItemArr]
            }
        }

    } else {

        print("No Data from Search/FilterVC Controller")
    }
}
```

Can anyone help? It seems like it would be the simple task to find the value and then filter out the dictionaries that are not equal to the `itemName` string, but I keep hitting a wall. And running into for-in loops myself :P trying different things to achieve the same task.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I hope I understood what you were asking.  You mention an "array of dictionaries" but you don't actually have an array of dictionaries anywhere in the code you've posted.

As far as I can tell, you are asking how to find all the entries in the `found` array for which `itemName` equals the `filterItemName` property.

If so, all you should need to do is:

`let foundItems = found.filter { $0.itemName == filterItemName }`

That's it.

---

Some other ideas:

If you want to search for items where `filterItemName` is contained in the `itemName`, you could do something like this:

`let foundItems = found.filter { $0.itemName.contains(filterItemName) }`

You could also make use of the `lowercased()` function if you want to do case-insensitive search.

You could also return properties of your found elements into an array:

`let foundIds = found.filter { $0.itemName == filterItemName }.map { $0.itemId }`

Comment: omg, that is what I missing. I was writing before let foundItems = found.filter{ 0$.itemName == "\(filterItemName)"} and i was getting all the arrays back not just the ones equal to filterItemName. The map one isn't necessary because I need the entire array for annotation later on in the project. I think that is totally what I needed. Damn. I have spent days on just a simple logic statement. Now I just need to append that array to one that uses my annotation circleQuery and I think I have solved it. Ill go check it and ill see if it exactly what I needed...Thank you.

Comment: I hesitated because I am going to post this app in the app store, I changed the names of my class variables along with my function variables. I have been working on this app for over a month now by myself. And I am hoping to get some ad revenue and possibly sell it as I recently lost my job. Thanks again

Comment: Yes the  let foundItems = found.filter { $0.itemName.contains(filterItemName) } was the exact solution I was looking for, cant believe I spent so much time on something so simple. I should have just posted this question days ago.

Comment: A good bit of programming advice is if you get stuck on something for more than a day ask for help. Sometimes talking things out is enough, sometimes other people will see like I did that you've just gone down the wrong path entirely.  It happens to *everyone* sometimes.  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 11):

Sort array of dictionary using the following way

```
var dict:[[String:AnyObject]] = sortedArray.filter{($0["parentId"] as! String) == "compareId"}
```

The **filter** function loops over every item in a collection, and returns a collection containing only items that satisfy an include condition.

We can get single object from this array of dictionary , you can use the following code

```
var dict = sortedArray.filter{($0["parentId"] as! String) == "compareId"}.first
```

OR

```
 let dict = sortedArray.filter{ ($0["parentId"] as! String) == "compareId" }.first
```

Answer (score 0):

Local search filter using predicate in array of dictionary objects 
  with key name this code use for both swift3 and swift4,4.1 also.

```
  func updateSearchResults(for searchController: 
       UISearchController) {

   if (searchController.searchBar.text?.characters.count)! > 0 {
       guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text, 
       searchText != "" else {
           return
       }
       usersDataFromResponse.removeAll()
       let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "userName 
        CONTAINS[C] %@", searchText)

       usersDataFromResponse = (filteredArray as 
        NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)

       print ("array = \(usersDataFromResponse)")

       self.listTableView.reloadData()
    }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I use CoreData And I have Array of Dictionary .
Here I am filter the key paymentToInvoice that value is invoice array then key invoiceToPeople that key contain People Dictionary then I search FirstName, lastName, Organization multiple key contain searchText.
I hope it's helps Please try this Thank You

```
  var searchDict = dict.filter { (arg0) -> Bool in

       let (key, value) = arg0
       for paymentInfo in (value as! [PaymentInfo]){
            let organization = (Array((value as! [PaymentInfo])[0].paymentToInvoice!)[0] as! InvoiceInfo).invoiceToPeople?.organization
            let firstName = (Array((value as! [PaymentInfo])[0].paymentToInvoice!)[0] as! InvoiceInfo).invoiceToPeople?.firstName
            let lastName = (Array((value as! [PaymentInfo])[0].paymentToInvoice!)[0] as! InvoiceInfo).invoiceToPeople?.lastName
            return organization?.localizedStandardRange(of: searchText) != nil || firstName?.localizedStandardRange(of: searchText) != nil || lastName?.localizedStandardRange(of: searchText) != nil
       }
       return true
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter based on a key value from array of dictionary, this is how it can be done.

```
incidentTransitionArray.filter{($0.isDisabled) == false}
```

Here incidentTransitionArray is an array of dictionaries.