# Search name or number in `UISearchbar`

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

In `tableViewCell` I have `userNameLbl` with name, `userClgLbl` with number. I want to search and show data in `tableView` either name search or number search.

If user search name - based on name I can show data in tableView.
If user search number - based on number I can show data in tableView.

But how to work with both name and number for single search bar. Actually here my data is dynamic from server and number is not phone number.

`UISearchBarDelegate` added to my class

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar()
var filteredData: [Any]!
@IBOutlet weak var listTblView: UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return filteredData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell


    cell.userNameLbl.text = filteredData[indexPath.row] as? String
    cell.userClgLbl.text = clg_uniq[indexPath.row] as? String

    return cell

} 

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    let strArr:[String] = clg_uniq as! [String]
    filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? clg_uniq : strArr.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
        // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
        return dataString.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    })

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.listTblView.reloadData()
    }
    if searchText == "" {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}

//Added these lines after json parsing 
self.filteredData = self.clg_uniq
self.listTblView.reloadData()
```

My example JSON data is

```
{"log" =     (
            {
        Name = "Name1";
        "clg_uniq" = 5c640e7b86e35;
    },
            {
         Name = "Name2";
        "clg_uniq" = <null>;
    },
            {
         Name = <null>;
        "clg_uniq" = 5c647af5d5c4d;
    },
            {
         Name = "Name4";
        "clg_uniq" = 5c647a0427253;
    },
            {
         Name = <null>;
        "clg_uniq" = <null>;
    },
            {
         Name = "Name6";
        "clg_uniq" = $cuniq";
    },
 )
}
```

Comment: Can you attach `json` response.

Comment: @ Amir Khan, I updated my question

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570716/swift-3-filter-array-of-dictionaries-by-string-value-of-key-in-dictionary

Comment: @ Amir Khan, its not helped to me

Comment: Ok let me fix it for you :)

Comment: Check my answer below.

Comment: Any update here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add following variables -**

```
var logArray = [Dictionary<String, Any>]() // For all result
var searchedLogArray = [Dictionary<String, Any>]() // For filtered result
var searchActive = false // whenever user search anything
```

**Replace** `UISearchBarDelegate` -

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    searchActive = searchText.count > 0 ? true : false

    let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Name CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)
    let clgUniqPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "clg_uniq CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)

    let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate.init(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [namePredicate, clgUniqPredicate])

    searchedLogArray = logArray.filter({
        return compoundPredicate.evaluate(with: $0)
    })

    listTblView.reloadData()

}
```

**Replace** `UITableViewDataSource` -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return searchActive ? searchedLogArray.count : logArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell

    let logDict = searchActive ? searchedLogArray[indexPath.row] : logArray[indexPath.row]

    // Name
    if let name = log["Name"] as? String{

      cell.userNameLbl.text = name

    }else{

      cell.userNameLbl.text = ""

    }


    // clg_uniq
    if let clgUniq = log["clg_uniq"] as? String {

         cell.userClgLbl.text = clgUniq

    }else{

         cell.userClgLbl.text = ""

    }


    return cell

}
```

I hope you are persing response as `Dictionary<String, Any>`

Let me know if you are still having any issue.

Comment: hai your code working fine tank you. But I got some problem, if response has null values it's crashed. For that I changed code in **textDidChange** like _searchedLogArray = logArray.filter({ (log) -> Bool in
            let param1 = log["Name"] as? String
            let param2 = log["clg_uniq"] as? String
            return (param1)?.lowercased().contains(searchText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).lowercased()) ?? false
                || (param2)?.lowercased().contains(searchText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).lowercased()) ?? false
        })_ Now labels printing <null> text

Comment: @iOS let me check

Comment: @iOS Check my updated answer and let me know whether you are still having any issue

Comment: The code will be working on those which has both values name and clg_uniq. So what you want - if there is only one value exist still working  right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191008/discussion-between-ios-and-amir-khan).

Comment: Here you please search $cuniq value, it's not searching anything.

Comment: Happy coding :)

Comment: Can you please explain this line for me Mobile CONTAINS[c] %@

Comment: actually I know about CONTAINS[c], but how **Mobile** can get total data

Comment: @iOS  there is "Name" I guess, no "Mobile"

Comment: Actually name is one of my key value in response. But how it can search

Comment: @iOS there are two parameter `Name` and `clg_uniq` so search will be taken place with the parameters.

Comment: Ok , automatically it will take care of that. am I right

Comment: @iOS yes these predicates deal with the parameters inside the array of dictionary. Doesn't matter whether its value is same as parameter name

Comment: @ Amir Khan, can you solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373430/twitter-error-your-credentials-do-not-allow-access-to-this-resource